# Looking for medieval werewolf fantasy book probably published in 1990s or up to 2010

Tags: story-identification, werewolf, medieval

The main protagonist was a young woman whose father was either making her marry someone or go on a pilgrimage. The setting seemed to be England, in fall or winter.  The werewolf accompanied her as she escaped on horseback from the group she was with.  The werewolf was able to survive being in old churches and holy places, where they hid?  At some point they, or perhaps just the werewolf, helped a sick or dying priest.

I believe there was more than one book in this series. The book was fairly thick. It was in the adult sci-fi/fantasy section in my library. I am fairly certain the author was female.

The protagonist's name may have been Claudia.

Comment: Hi Chris. This is awfully vague. If you can think of anything more specific that would help. Things like specific plot elements or names of people or places.

Comment: Gillian Bradshaw's 'The Wolf Hunt' was published in 2001, and is certainly medieval. The main character is a woman who is trying to avoid being forced into marriage ... but I read it so long ago I wouldn't dare go further than that.